# Валидация input[type=radio]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form, jquery-validation

Народ, подскажите кто может знает, как в этот цикл добавить проверку на заполнение input [type="radio"]. Сейчас проверяет только текстовые input

```
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "")  {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }

  }

  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
...............
if (y[i].type == "radio") {
   if (!y[i].checked){
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
   }
}else{
   if (y[i].value == "")  {
   // add an "invalid" class to the field:
   y[i].className += " invalid";
   // and set the current valid status to false
   valid = false;
  }
}
.............
```